# How can I dynamically get words surrounding a keyword?

Tags: r, regex

I have a sentence that may contain keywords. I search for them, if one is true, I want the word before and after the keyword.

```
cont <- c("could not","would not","does not","will not","do not","were not","was not","did not")
text <- "this failed to increase incomes and production did not improve"
str_extract(text,"([^\\s]+\\s+){1}names(which(sapply(cont,grepl,text)))(\\s+[^\\s]+){1}")
```

This fails when I dynamically search using the names function but if I input:

```
str_extract(text,"([^\\s]+\\s+){1}did not(\\s+[^\\s]+){1}")
```

it correctly returns: production did not improve.
How can I get this to function without directly inputing the keywords?
Final note: I do not completely understand the syntax used to get surrounding objects. Basic r books have not covered this. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 4):

You could use your `cont` vector to create a vector of regex strings:

```r
targets <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s+){1}", cont, "(\\s+[^\\s]+){1}")
```

Which you can feed into `str_extract_all` and then unlist:

```r
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(text, targets))
#> [1] "production did not improve"
```

If this is something you need to do quite frequently, you could wrap it in a function:

```r
get_surrounding <- function(string, keywords) {
  targets <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s+){1}", keywords, "(\\s+[^\\s]+){1}")
  unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(string, targets))
}
```

With which you can easily run the query on new strings:

```r
new_text <- "The production did not increase because the manager would not allow it."

get_surrounding(new_text, cont)
#> [1] "manager would not allow"     "production did not increase"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can try this

```
> regmatches(text, gregexpr(sprintf("\\w+\\s(%s)\\s\\w+", paste0(cont, collapse = "|")), text))[[1]]
[1] "production did not improve"
```

Answer (score 0):

Each match of the following regular expression will save the preceding and following words in capture groups 1 and 2, respectively.

```
\\b([a-z]+) +(?:could|would|does|will|do|were|was|did) +not +([a-z]+)\\b
```

You will of course have to form this expression programmatically, but that should be straightforward.

Hover the cursor over each element of the expression at this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJ0diB/1) to obtain an explanation of its function.

For the string

```
"she could not believe that production did not improve"
```

there are two matches. For the first ("she could not believe") "she" and "believe" are saved to capture groups 1 and 2, respectively. For the second ("production did not improve") "production" and "improve" are saved to capture groups 1 and 2, respectively.